# pygtk: use window object as a class

Tags: gtk, window, pygtk, radix, extends

Some programmers create Window classes:

```
class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    ...
```

I've defined my window with Glade and then i can get it with:

```
xmlTree.get_widget('window')
```

Is there a way to use this object as class and extends it? I want to handle it as other programmers do but using my defined window. I don't want to get a class and a window property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of is to use Glade to construct an Alignment laid out with widgets as you would want your window to look. Your class can then be something like:

```
class PyApp(gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self, filename, widget_name):
    # Use builder to open filename
    ...
    # and then add the alignment widget:
    self.add(builder.get_object(widget_name))
```

Comment: What do you think about it? How do you do that? Thank you.

Comment: @thom - I don't understand your questions.

Comment: Which approach do you use? Do you handle windows as classes or how do you do that? Thank you.

Comment: This is how I do a lot of my widget layouts (even non-windows). I put the builder stuff in a subclass, though, because there's actually quite a few lines of code needed.